# How to check jsp file under web-inf by custom tag?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm trying to check if a file under WEB-INF/view file.
I am using Spring and JSP 2.0 currently, and trying to make a forum theme.
In a custom tag, I am trying to check if the jsp file exists inside the directory, but I can't get it working...

```
File file = new File("./skin/login", "login.jsp");
login.jsp is included as /WEB-INF/view/skin/login/login.jsp
```

Is there anyway to check this file if it exists??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ServletContext.getRealPath()` method to construct absolute path from *virtual* path.

```
String realPath=getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/view/skin/login/login.jsp");

File file = new File(realPath);

if(file.exists()) {
   //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (file.exists()) {
    //do what you want if file exists
} else {
    //do what you want if file doesn't exist
}
```